# Very slow Internet speed due to proxy

Tags: networking, software-center, internet, proxy

I have just installed Ubuntu and I am totally a noob.
My proxy was 172.31.1.4:8080
and i added these settings to run the internet
mozilla get the normal speed but when i try to download anything from the Software Center
I get only 17 kB/s....I had to wait 80 minutes to install Gnome

Kindly help
I am using a wired connection

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't too easy to fix.

Proxies by nature are usually notoriously slow. The best way to fix this is to simply disable the proxy when not necessary. For example, if it is a business proxy, ONLY enable it when on-campus or when you need to access something on the company network.

You can also contact the proxy administrator to see if they can do something to speed it up. However, they probably won't be able to do anything.